# How to refactor HttpURLConnection header settings

Tags: android, refactoring, httpurlconnection

Everytime I need to send an HttpURLConnection, I need to set lots of properties
like this:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(ConnectStateVar.connExpireTime);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
conn.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setDoOutput(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

The question is that I have lots of simliar settings. How should I refactor these code?
I don't want to view lots of same copies.

Comment: Create a method that does all of the above for you, potentially returning the connection so you can make further modifications as required?

Comment: Well, how about creating a class instead and new the instance object as global variable. Each time I need it, I call that global variable?

Comment: I just wondering can I use `apache.http.HttpEntity`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't reuse connections, so semantically it would make more sense to me to have something return a new `URLConnection` instance for every connection attempt. Up to you whether you prefer to wrap it into some sort of `ConnectionManager` entity, or have a static util method somewhere. `HttpEntity` is meant to be used with `HttpClient` and won't play nice with `URLConnection`. Might be better to set up your own POJO instead, or use a `Map` or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a method that sets the constant request properties and provide the variable properties as arguments:

```
void initConnection(URLConnection conn, String contentType, ... <other variable headers as arguments>) {
    // set the constant header values
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/       xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

    //set the variable headers passed as arguments. For example ContentType
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
}
```

Comment: But I want to extract the HTTP header to a list and create another list containing the value information. Finally, using a loop to set the connection's property up could be great. Or should I use a map? Or any more flexible solution?

Comment: Map sounds good - you can populate it with a <Key, Value> tuple and use each tuple for each Header property. You can also make a predefined map for properties that don't change and another one for dynamic properties